# ALSA mix mpd and line-in input through equaliser

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

I'm setting up MPD on rPi and using a Behringer UCA202 as output. However, I also want to use this hardware to play a line-in (eg to play video etc from my computer) - and apply an equalizer setting to both (precluding the easy answer of using the device's monitor option). So I guess:

- Capture hw:5,0
- Mix in mpd playback
- Send this mix through the equaliser
- Send the result to hw:5,0

For some reason this hardware doesn't show up in alsamixer > capture ('This sound device does not have any capture controls') but it does show up in `arecord` and I know I can send the input to the output, having done so from the command line with:

`alsaloop -C hw:5,0 -P hw:5,0`

I also know I can get MPD working through the equaliser:

```
ctl.equal {
    type equal;
}

pcm.equalizer {
    type equal
    slave.pcm "plughw:5,0"
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm equalizer
}
```

I have experimented with dmix but my alsa-fu is lacking; I'm not really understanding what combination of things I need to do to get this working (if it's at all possible). Ideally avoiding installing pulse - am trying to keep this lightweight on the Pi.